# How to trigger a JS controller action with Minitest

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, integration-testing, minitest

In a test I want to simulate a request that only accepts JS requests. I tried it in the "normal" style:

```
patch study_update_user_vocab_path(@user, @vocabs[index]), 
                                { strength: "1", resume_study_index: "index" }
```

Here, "strength" and "resume_study_index" are the ids of the form fields. When running the test I get the following error message:

```
 ActionView::MissingTemplate: ActionView::MissingTemplate: Missing template vocabs/study_update, application/study_update with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :jbuilder, :coffee]}.
```

This makes perfect sense, as there is no view to render. But how can I tell Mini:Test to trigger/expect JS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can think of two ways.

1. In your routes, add `defaults: { formats: 'js' } }` to study_update_user_vocab_path. So it would be `patch 'blah/path', to: 'controller#action', as: :study_update_user_vocab, defaults: { formats: 'js' } }`
2. In your test, write out the full path and add .js to the end. So `patch "/users/#{@user.id}/vocabs/#{vocabs[index]}.js", { strength: "1", resume_study_index: "index" }`

Comment: To 1.: When I add the default parameter to the route, I get this error: `ActionController::UrlGenerationError: No route matches {:action=>"study_update", :controller=>"vocabs", :format=>nil, :id=>nil, ...`. It doesn't look like the route is valid. I did this in my routes.rb: `patch   'study_update', defaults: { format: 'js' } ` Is anything wrong with that?

Answer (score 0):

In controller tests you don't pass the path of the request to `patch`, you pass the action, which is the name of the method. I assume the method on your controller is `update_user_vocab`, so if I am wrong swap that out with the name of your method.

```
patch :update_user_vocab, id: @vocabs[index], # The record ID you are working with?
                          strength: "1", # I assume this is some needed query param
                          resume_study_index: "index", #same
                          format: "js" # send this as a js request
```

Comment: It is actually an integration test. Does that make any difference for my situation? In your answer, what about the user.id? I figured you forgot it and tried this: `patch :study_update_user_vocab, id: @vocabs[index], user_id: @user.id, strength: "1", resume_study_index: "index", format: "js"` and I got the following error message: `ArgumentError: ArgumentError: bad argument (expected URI object or URI string)` So it looks like it's expecting a path rather than an action? Is this expectation changing with different test types (controller, integration, ..)?

Comment: Try `patch study_update_user_vocab_path(@user, @vocabs[index], format: :js), { strength: "1", resume_study_index: "index" }`